# Filtering an .xml and then display items IF any are left

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an .xml which I need to display using XSL. Now, the entities in the XML are videos with tags. Not sure if it matters, but a video can have multiple tags.

**Goal:** What I need to do, is to (for a specific page) show all items that have the tag "cat1" for example. This is simple enough, I'll just use an if:

```
<xsl:if test="tag[. =&#34;cat1&#34;]">
```

However, it should also NOT list the h1-tag in case there are no items tagged with "cat1" - that should only be displayed IF there are any videos with the tag "cat1".

**Problem:** If there ARE videos with "cat1" present, no problem.
If there ARE NO videos with the tag "cat1" present, the h1-tag will be shown, but no videos. This is obviously not acceptable.

So the question becomes;

How do I filter the video-items first by checking their tags, and only after making sure there are still videos left, display the rest of the code?

Here is the code for the xml:

```
<videos>
    <video>
        <title>Video title</title>
        <subtitle></subtitle>
        <description_long>
            <![CDATA[Description]]>
        </description_long>
        <link language="English">http://URL here</link>
        <tag>cat1</tag>
    </video>
</demos>
```

Here is the code for the .xsl I've been trying:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="videos/video">
        <xsl:sort data-type="text" order="ascending" />
        <xsl:if test="tag[. =&#34;cat1&#34;]">
            <h1>Category 1 videos</h1>
            <div class="video">
                <xsl:value-of select="title" />
            </div>
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="video[tag='cat1'][1]">
  <h1>Category 1 videos</h1>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="../video[tag='cat1']" mode="process"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="video" mode="process">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="title"/></p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be well-formed and added a second `video` element):

```
<videos>
    <video>
        <title>Video title</title>
        <subtitle></subtitle>
        <description_long><![CDATA[Description]]></description_long>
        <link language="English">http://URL here</link>
        <tag>cat1</tag>
    </video>
    <video>
        <title>Video title 2</title>
        <subtitle></subtitle>
        <description_long><![CDATA[Description]]></description_long>
        <link language="English">http://URL here</link>
        <tag>cat1</tag>
    </video>
</videos>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<h1>Category 1 videos</h1>
<p>Video title</p>
<p>Video title 2</p>
```

**When applied on this XML document** (no cat1):

```
<videos>
    <video>
        <title>Video title</title>
        <subtitle></subtitle>
        <description_long><![CDATA[Description]]></description_long>
        <link language="English">http://URL here</link>
        <tag>cat2</tag>
    </video>
    <video>
        <title>Video title 2</title>
        <subtitle></subtitle>
        <description_long><![CDATA[Description]]></description_long>
        <link language="English">http://URL here</link>
        <tag>cat2</tag>
    </video>
</videos
```

>

**again the wanted answer (nothing) is produced.**

Comment: Thanks! This pretty much solved it. Except for one thing: It only lists one, as there is no for-each in it. I have fiddled with it but can't get it to work, it only wants to display a single item.

Comment: @Patrik Fredriksson: I cannot repro the problem you are having with this solution. I edited my answer and now it contains an XML document with two `video`elements. The result has output for both of them -- contrary to your statement that it would show data from only one of them. Just copy and paste the new XML document and run the transformation on it -- you should get the same answer that I am getting.

Comment: Oh gosh I'm such a cluts. I did the test thinking there were two "cat1" entities when I had in fact copy/pasted the wrong entity. Sry about that.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help by the way. Immensely lowers my future workload on this project! :)